# Braintree iOS Drop-in Payment UI customization

Tags: paypal, braintree

I am using Drop-in Payment UI in iOS.
Basically i am using this SDK for subscription purpose.
So at the time of adding a new card, Drop-In UI is shown with "Pay
with a card" text, which is not a correct text in my case as User is
not paying at that time, he is just subscribing for a service.
So is there any way to change that text?

Please check below screen shot with highlighted text.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support][support].</sub>

There is no way to change text or access fields in the Drop-In UI. To have more control over the interface, the [developer docs for client-side payment processing](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/client-side/ios/v4) have instructions on how to tokenize payment information without the Drop-In UI.